# Arduino, Proteus, Pythony Proteus. Problemas con la comunicacion serial desde python a arduino

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, jupyter

tengo un problema y es el siguiente, el problema llega con el python y ubidots. En ubidtos envia un valor 1 o 0 si esta apagado o prendido con un switch y python deberia mandar el caracter 'U' pero no ocurre eso, en arduino al ver que esta recibiendo o si esta recibiendo sale este caracter ÿ. Entonces como puedo hacer que python envie un caracter a ardunio??

Nota: en las conexiones como no tenia los puertos suficentes tuve que crear unos extra, uso en el visual studio code python 3.10.2 con jupyter y tapo los token y demas por seguridad.
Arduino 1

```
//Arduino 1
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#include<DHT.h>
#define DHTPIN A5
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN,DHTTYPE);
SoftwareSerial myserial(12,13);
SoftwareSerial myblue2(2,3);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);//Serial fisica
  myserial.begin(9600);//Serial virtual
  myblue2.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();//Inicio sensor DHT
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  myserial.println("Arduino 1: ");
}

void loop() {
  float h=dht.readHumidity();
  float t=dht.readTemperature();
  float ar=Serial.parseFloat();
  char res;
  res=myblue2.read();
  //char r=Serial.read();
  
  myserial.print("Humedad DHT11: ");
  myserial.println(h);
  myserial.print("Temperatura DHT22:");
  myserial.println(ar);
  
  myserial.println(res);

  myblue2.print(h);
  myblue2.print(",");
  myblue2.println(ar);
  if (myblue2.available()>0){
    res=myblue2.read();
    if(res=='U'){
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    }if(res=='X'){
      digitalWrite(8,LOW);
    }
  }
  
  delay(1000);
}
```

Python con ubidots

```
#from opcode import HAVE_ARGUMENT
from ubidots import ApiClient
from serial import Serial
import serial
import time

serialArduino = Serial(port='COM5', baudrate=9600, timeout=None)
new_vale=1
while True:
    while(serialArduino.readline()==0): 
        pass
    dat1=serialArduino.readline().decode('utf-8')
    #print(type(dat1))
    print(dat1)
    humtem=dat1.split(",")
    #data=float(serialArduino.readline().decode('utf-8'), sep=",",decimal=".")
    hume=float(humtem[0])
    print(hume)
    temp=float(humtem[1])
    print(temp)
    api=ApiClient(token="XXXXX")

    humedad = api.get_variable('XXXXX')
    newHum=humedad.save_value({'value':hume})

    temperatua = api.get_variable('XXXXX')
    newHum=temperatua.save_value({'value':temp})

    led=api.get_variable('XXXXX')
    valled=led.get_values(1)
    
    if valled[0]['value']==1:
        serialArduino.write(b'U')
        print("Entra")
        print(valled)
    else:
        serialArduino.write(b'X')
        print("No")
        print(valled)
```

Estas son las conexiones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Describes un problema de comunicación entre Arduino y Python. Debes simplificar el problema, pues el segundo Arduino y todos los dispositivos adicionales no son parte de él.

Comment: Copie las partes relevantes de tu código y no encuentro ningún error en el envió/recepción de "X" y "U" desde Python a Arduino. La descripción del problema es confusa. Mejor simplifica el código (elimina el DHT11 y el segundo Arduino) para poder copiarlo tal cual. Conectando un led al pin 8 podremos comprobar el correcto funcionamiento del código.

Comment: No puedo hacerlo es que es un trabajo que se mando de esa manera y una pregunta, usaste el Serial.begin(); es decir el predeterminado el fisico del arduino o el otro Serial virtual myblue2.begin(); ya que viendo en videos y demas hacerlo con el predeterminado si envia el caracter pero con el myblue2 no lo hace, disculpa que este tan confuso

Comment: Bueno, si reduces el problema a algo que pueda llegar y copiar podría trabajar en él.

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que Serial,read() devuelve un entero no un caracter, lo que no se si es igual en  res=myblue2.read();   así que deberías cambiar a :  if(res==55){ , si mal no recuerdo

Comment: Intente lo que mencionaste y sigue igual, coloque que imprima para ver que dato mostraba y era 255 y en tipo char era ÿ dichos datos no cambiaban sin importar que intente enviar desde python